# Trying to use the parent function to add/remove css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a contact form where a user clicks on an input/textarea and the label appears at the top of the input/textarea like this:
[the correct outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViRIE.png)

I have created the HTML and CSS but my problem is with the Javascript(Jquery). Every time a user tries to type on one of the inputs all the labels appear which is not what I want to do.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Test for placeholder support
    $.support.placeholder = (function(){
        var i = document.createElement('input');
        return 'placeholder' in i;
    })();

    // Hide labels by default if placeholders are supported
    if($.support.placeholder) {
        $('.form-label').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('js-hide-label');
        });  

        // Code for adding/removing classes here
        $('.form-group').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function(e){

            // Cache our selectors
            var $this = $(this),
                $parent = $this.parent().find("label");

            if (e.type == 'keyup') {
                if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                    $('label').addClass('js-hide-label'); 
                } else {
                    $('label').removeClass('js-hide-label');   
                }                     
            } 
            else if (e.type == 'blur') {
                if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                    $('label').addClass('js-hide-label');
                } 
                else {
                    $('label').removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass('js-unhighlight-label');
                }
            } 
            else if (e.type == 'focus') {
                if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
                    $('label').removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
                }
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

The codepen to this problem  is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/EovXEX

Comment: `$('label')` is a global lookup.  It finds all the elements with that tag on the page.  If you want to find the label that is related to the input, then you need to perform a contextual lookup.  Typically these look like `$this.closest(selectorOfParentOfElementAndDesiredElement).find(selectorOfDesiredElement)`.  So if your input and label were children of a div you could do `$this.closest('div').find('label')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 2 changes and got this working. As Taplar mentioned in his comment, you were finding all labels. I updated that line to find the `prev` element of the parent div, which is the label for the `form-group`. I also changed your if else logic to use the $parent element you are caching(which is now the label element)

```
    // Code for adding/removing classes here
    $('.form-group').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function(e){

        // Cache our selectors
        var $this = $(this),
            // fixed this line to find prev()
            $parent = $(this).parent().prev();

        // update all of the statements to use $parent(link element)
        if (e.type == 'keyup') {
            if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                $parent.addClass('js-hide-label'); 
            } else {
                $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');   
            }                     
        } 
        else if (e.type == 'blur') {
            if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
            } 
            else {
                $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass('js-unhighlight-label');
            }
        } 
        else if (e.type == 'focus') {
            if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
                $parent.removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: My only other recommendation would be to use variable names that are more clear. As Alex suggested in his answer, I would rename both $this and $parent to input and label respectively, just to make the code easier to read and maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the hide classes see the portion of corrected:

```js
                if (e.type == 'keyup') {
                    if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                        $('label').removeClass('js-hide-label');
                    } else {
                        $('label').addClass('js-hide-label');

                    }
                }
```

or you can do:

```js
                if (e.type == 'keyup') {
                    if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                        $('label').removeClass('js-hide-label');
                    } else {
                        $('label').addClass('js-hide-label');
                        $this.parent().prev().removeClass();
                        $this.parent().prev().addClass('form-label');
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This part was actually working properly, he wants to add the `js-hide-label` when the input is blank.

Comment: This is still wrong. You don't need to touch the form-label class, and you are still removing/adding the classes in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors.
The $parent variable incorrectly select the label associated, and its name does not match what it does. Rename it in $label.
Then replace all $('label') by $label.

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzjjxN?editors=1010

Fixed code :

```
var $this = $(this),
$label = $this.closest('.form-group').find("label");


if (e.type == 'keyup') {
                if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                    $label.addClass('js-hide-label'); 
                } else {
                    $label.removeClass('js-hide-label');   
                }                     
            } 
            else if (e.type == 'blur') {
                if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                    $label.addClass('js-hide-label');
                } 
                else {
                    $label.removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass('js-unhighlight-label');
                }
            } 
            else if (e.type == 'focus') {
                if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
                    $label.removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
                }
            }
```